# Gallery for JQuery version 1.2.6 or below

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

Now I'm working with old web-site(developed at 2008 or 2009). I have simple task to install some kind of gallery, like item's pictures preview in e-shops to be precisely.
So I tried to integrate this plugins: Rebox, Fancybox, Lightbox. All of them need JQuery 1.11.1 or above... but i'm dealing with JQuery 1.2.6

Then I tried to update JQuery version on web-site. My plugin began to work, but all other plugins  broke...
All day i spent searching for plugin compatible with JQuery v.1.2.6 or below, but found nothing. 
Maybe somebody have plugin what i need, or should I write my own plugin in this situation?

Comment: 1.2.6 is over 8 years old. About time you bite the bullet and update the code. It is not that simple since a lot has changed in jQuery over those 8 years. You might be able to go the noConflict mode to get a new library to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found fancyZoom plugin(don't confuse with fancyBox) for jQuery 1.2.6. For now it works fine, no bugs detected.